VLOOKUP in another Excel sheet returning #N/A
In an Excel workbook, I have two sheets: Repo and Data. I want to use VLOOKUP in Data, where the lookup is performed in Repo. I input the parameters in VLOOKUP by manually clicking the sheets and selecting the range.
In the table array parameter, when I click Repo, the name Repo gets inputted to VLOOKUP correctly like so: VLOOKUP(D2,'Repo'). But once I select the entire range of cells in Repo, the name changes to Table_ExternalData_13[#All] in the VLOOKUP. The resulting cell is #N/A. I would like the formula to look like VLOOKUP(D2,'Repo'!$A$1:$D$59,2,FALSE), which has worked in the past. I'm stumped as to what is causing the error. I've checked to make sure that the data in D2 of 'Data' is actually in 'Repo'.
EDITed to add examples. I also noticed that Repo was a table as @bdpolinsky has suggested, so I converted it to a Range using Table Design > Convert to Range. Doing this has not solved the issue.
I've also tried manually writing in 'Repo'!$A$1:$D$59 which does not work.
Data:



Website
Product




Discover



Ally




Repo:



Website
Product
Env




Discover
Banking
PROD


Ally
Banking
NPRD


...





I would like to get the Product data from Repo and put it in the Product column of Data.

A few things to check when using vlookup would be that the data you're searching for is in column A of Repo, as vlookups count from the leftmost column selected. Make sure there isn't trailing spaces on your inputs or the column you're searching as well.

=VLOOKUP(D2,Table_ExternalData_13,2,FALSE) means look for D2 in the first column of the table (data range (without [#All])) and return the value in the corresponding row of the 2nd column (2). If <ou want to return a value to the left of the lookup column, you cannot use VLOOKUP.

So have you verified whether do you have any leading or trailing spaces? or any non printable characters. How is the Repo Sheet created ? Does those datas are manually entered on that sheet or resourced from External sources?

@MayukhBhattacharya there are no leading/trailing spaces nor weird characters in both the column names and the VLOOKUP formula. The Repo sheet was created as a copy of another sheet which is a table. I have since converted the table in Repo to a Range (plain data). There are no connections to external workbooks/sheets/data.

Hmm, try this once =CODE(MID('Repo'!$A1,SEQUENCE(,LEN('Repo'!$A1)),1)) and fill down till row 9 and to see any number is not between 65-90 and 97-122, because one cant say anything from Markdown Data, what you have in your actual source. It will be assumptions and guess work, which is pointless i think! From here with the given data it should work, but the same simple formula is not working on your end, so need to verify the data. Offtopic btw is Ally Financial Bank ?

Note that non-printable characters cant be seen with unaided eye/human eye or plain sight.

Also - use the type() function to try and assess whether you have a type mismatch in your data. While what I've seen on the internet says that vlookup works just fine with text strings, there's more opportunity for little things to get in the way. You can use the int() function and the text() function to convert things to numbers or text if you need to.
